# WPF DataGrid sorting not doing, if the source is replaced by a new collection

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have a list of objects, each contains a collection. I need a possibility to select a object from the list and display the collection. The collection should be sorted by a some property.

So, I have a ComboBox to display a list of objects. And a DataGrid to display a selected object's collection. I use a CollectionViewSource to sort a DataGrid. It work... but only first time. After selecting other object from the list, DataGrid are no longer sorted.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:componentModel="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedValues" 
                              Source="{Binding SelectedCategory.Values}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Value" Direction="Ascending" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categories}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCategory}"/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedValues}}"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False">
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        Categories = new ObservableCollection<MyCategory>
        {
            new MyCategory
            {
                Name = "Cat1",
                Values = new ObservableCollection<MyValue>
                {
                    new MyValue {Value = 5},
                    new MyValue {Value = 4},
                    new MyValue {Value = 3},
                    new MyValue {Value = 2},
                    new MyValue {Value = 1},
                }
            },

            new MyCategory
            {
                Name = "Cat2",
                Values = new ObservableCollection<MyValue>
                {
                    new MyValue {Value = 15},
                    new MyValue {Value = 14},
                    new MyValue {Value = 13},
                    new MyValue {Value = 12},
                    new MyValue {Value = 11},
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyCategory> Categories { get; set; }

    public MyCategory SelectedCategory
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCategory;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedCategory = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private MyCategory _selectedCategory;


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}

public class MyCategory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyValue> Values { get; set; }
}

public class MyValue
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: As I understand from your question the datagridview content would change in accordance with the item selected in the ComboBox, if that is the case, then in OnPropertyChangedEvent you have to clear the datagridview if it has any data.

Comment: DataGridView content are changed, it is ok. Problem is what the content sorted only after first selection in the ComboBox, after next selection the content not sorted.